# Serial console cable choice

Tags: serial-console

It is my understanding that the recommended console cable for the Raspberry Pi is [this](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_TTL-232R_RPi.pdf) one (the TTL cable). I currently have [this](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_TTL-232R_CABLES.pdf) cable. My question is weather I can use this cable to establish a console connection with the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to plug the non-USB end into the Pi's UART (gpios 14/15, pins 8/10 on the Pi's expansion header).

All the Pi's gpios are 3V3.  As long as you are using a 3V3 variant of the cable with USB on one end and wires on the other it should be fine.

You need to connect RX, TX, and ground for the serial link to work.

Comment: So you are saying that my cable is good to go? Because it is indeed the 3.3V version. My issue is that the recommended cable has only 3 leads instead of 5 that mine has.

Comment: Model TTL-232R-3V3-WE? Shows 6 wires not 5. Connect black to ground, orange (TXD) to Pi RXD, and yellow (RXD) to Pi TXD. Leave RTS/CTS/VCC unconnected (but insulated).

Comment: You are right. It is 6, not 5. But I do not have the open ended version. Mine has the connector and I would like to plug it as is on the GPIO. I do not want to cut the connector if possible.

Comment: There is no way (which will work) to fit the connnector over the gpio pins.  I suppose it's female.  You'll need to get three female to male jumpers to connect the socket to the Pi's pins.